# Backslash in string keeps being treated as making an escaped character

Tags: javascript

I have a string returned from a javascript API call they are like these:

```
"#|net\brown_gf"
"#|net\nugent_he"
```

I then need to use these strings as they are to pass them to another api call on a different system. The problem is `\b` or `\n` of the string are being treated as escaped characters and nothing I have tried allows me to add an extra backslash to escape the slash.

The string I recieve is not able to be changed as it is from an api I have no access to modify and no choice but to use.

I am guessing my only option is to look for every escaped character combination and convert them back to what I want. Any simpler solution is requested, or a way to tell javascript that the string is a literal string with 0 escaped characters in it

Comment: Have you tried to use the js `encodeURIComponent` function ?

Comment: @johannchopin yes I have, the problem is it is the string being passed to `encodeURIComponent` is converting the sequences like `\n` to new lines before `encodeURIComponent` is called.

Comment: Try use quadruple slash like: `"#|net\nugent_he".replace('\n', '\\\\n')`

Comment: @hoangdv the problem is i don't know what escaped character will be passed from the server

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. Do you have JS function that returns the value (`===`) `"#|net\brown_gf"` or `"#|net\\brown_gf"` or `'"#|net\brown_gf"'` or `'"#|net\brown_gf"'`? And which of these do you want to pass forward?

Comment: You will have no problem if you use the combination of `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` fonctions

Comment: The function returns `#|net\brown_gf`

Comment: @Bullfrog has a string or ... ?

Comment: @johannchopin this is returned as a string

Comment: The "backslash is escape" is a source code only feature, when you have a backslash in a value is stays that. Unless you are treating that value as source. You need to explain more about how you get the value and how you are working with it

Comment: @HansKeﬆing that makes perfect sense, now that I understand that it is working. I was testing the API by copying the response over to the new API and was getting the errors, now I have tested it by feeding the APIs into each other and it works.
If you write a an answer I will mark it as correct to give you the credit you deserve. I will also look at how to reword this question to make it easier to understand. Thanks again